# Complex regex to transform from legacy sql code

Tags: regex

Is it possible to transform sentences of the following form

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#tmpX') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpX;      (1)
```

To the following

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpX;                                      (2)
```

What I need to effectively is the following pseudo-code:

1. Identify rows of code that are of the form (1)
2. Extract the temporary table name - in this case #tmpX:
     The temp table name always begins # but can be any length (without spaces)
3. Add the name found in step 2 to the string `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`
4. Append a semi-colon onto the result of 3.

I use sql-server but not interested in it's leftfield regex functionality - so will open the sql file in either notepad++ or komodo edit - so standard regex is what I'll use.

(apologies that I have no definite attempt included but my regex is very limited)

Comment: Try `^IF OBJECT_ID\('[^'#]*(#[^\s']+)'\) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #\S+;$` -> `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $1;` (if the pattern should match the whole line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
IF \w+\(['"][^#]*(#\w+)['"]\) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE \1;
```

- `[^#]*(#\w+)` Match anything except `#` more or zero times then the table name.

Replace with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $1;
```